# How to delete fields and their data from controlled form?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an array `fields` which represents form fields. These fields are controlled, their values are stored in `form`.

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState([])
const [form, setForm] = useState({})
...
fields.map(function(element, index) {
    return <input name={'field '+element} key={index} />
})
```

I can add fields dynamically:

```
setFields([...fields, someNextField])
```

I can also delete fields:

```
setFields(function (fields) {
    const newFields = [...fields]
    newFields.splice(index, 1)
    return newFields
})
```

This is where the problem starts. Let's say, I have the following fields on screen:

```
field 1: foo
field 2: bar
```

Now if I delete `field 1`, I expect only this to remain:

```
field 2: bar
```

But instead I see this:

```
field 2: foo
```

While inside `form` it is as it should be. I also tried to delete `field 1` from `form` at the same time when I delete it from `fields`, but the result is still this.
Is there something that I miss about (re)rendering such forms?

Comment: That seems pretty strange. Are you including a `key` when you render your array of fields?

Comment: @Nick yes, I add `key` to the outermost element in `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index is not the right choice for a key if you plan to make the elements removable. Instead use some unique Id as a key.

Intially `field 1`'s key is 0. `field 2`'s key is 1. After deleting `field 1`, `field 2`'s key becomes 0. Now it's not the same element for React. Refer react's reconciliation doc to understand this better (https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)

Comment: I replaced `index` by a hash of `element` and it works now.